# C++, оператор приведения типа для enum class?

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов, приведение-типов

Никак не получается написать оператор приведения типа из `enum class` в, например,  `size_t`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Comment: Это встроенное преобразование, ничего писать не надо.

Comment: @VTT, мне кажется, что вы ошибаетесь. Неявное преобразование допустимо из `enum`, но не из `enum class`.

Comment: А явное - и в том, и в другом случае.

Comment: @VTT,  я понимаю это, но мне необходимо понять, как перегрузить оператор типа для `enum class`. Уже разные способы перепробовал, не получается.

Comment: Я же уже написал выше - ничего писать не надо, преобразование встроенное

Comment: @VTT, мне нужно написать преобразование, не для `size_t`. Как это сделать?

Comment: Опишите чего у вас там не получается конкретно в вопросе....

Comment: Невозможно перегрузить оператор преобразования типа для `enum class` типа. Зачем вам это понадобилось, если преобразование к `size_t` и так уже есть, как вам ясно уже объяснили? Ответы вроде "мне нужно" тут никому не интересны.

Comment: @AnT, я хочу написать оператор приведения типа, который сможет преобразовать значение из `enum class A` в какой-то другой тип, не обязательно `size_t`. Например `enum class A -> MyClass B` Как это сделать?

Comment: @MGNeo Никак. Такой фичи в языке нет.

Comment: @AnT, то есть, для `enum class` невозможно перегрузить `operator Type`?

Comment: Вам надо сделать в `MyClass` конструктор, принимающий `enum class A`.

Comment: @MGNeo Да именно так. Перегрузка некоторых операторов возможна только для классов. Операторы приведения типа как раз относятся к таковым.

Comment: @AnT, если у вас есть ссылка на место, в котором эта ситуация описывается в `Стандарте`, я буду вам очень признателен.

Comment: @MGNeo Стандарт не выделяет это в отдельную "ситуацию". Понятие "функции преобразования" (conversion function) определено в стандарте языка только для класс-типов. Ни для каких других типов такого понятия не определено вообще. `enum class` не является класс-типом.

Comment: @AnT, я подумал, что `enum class` имеет отношение к типам ранга `class`.

Comment: @MGNeo Нет, не имеет.